# Avoid inserting duplicate records in c#

Tags: c#, ms-access

How to avoid inserting duplicate records in c#

For example:

Table name: record1 in that userName is primary key

1. insert record1.(userName=101, password=raj, confirmPassword=raj)
2. insert record2.(userName=102, password=kumar, confirmPassword=kumar)
3. insert record3.(userName=101, password=jose, confirmPassword=jose)

When the ok button is clicked it shows a message like

MessageBox.Show("User name already inserted. Please change username");

Comment: @Ivo: I like your question better than the original. :)

Comment: If its a homework question, then add homework tag to it.

Comment: Please edit the original question instead of posting a duplicate.

Comment: Eric give the good idea what he tell i just think and made changes in my code it works so once again i thanks ERIC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an index on the table on the userName column and make it Unique. This will throw an exception when a duplicate record is added.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with using a database system? Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but all you would do is run a query to see if the user exists or check on the SQL error returned if you have a constraint on the username.

If that is indeed what you were looking for, I think you should learn to use Google more often and learn SQL before diving into writing a system that requires it. :)

Comment: yes you are misunderstanding me because i am new for c# and database, if possible answer the question

Comment: @Rajashekhar here you shouldn't assist the people to answer your question like "if possible answer the question", here we are to help you thats it, not for your homeworks to be done.

Comment: i am not assist you, ok sorry off it

Answer (score 0):

You could catch the primary key violation and handle it with your error message.

Comment: i am new for c# and database pls show the code

Answer (score 0):

- Validate in your usertable (via a query)  that the username does not exist yet
- If not, insert, else show the messagebox

Comment: i am new for c# and database pls write the code for that